# Is it possible to load csv data to Highstock chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, highcharts

I have a Highcharts line chart and I would like to add a range selector to it. To do this, I read that you have to use Highstock, so I am trying to re-make the chart but it won't load the csv data. There is no error message or anything in the console, the lines just don't show up. Is there a different format/syntax I have to use? Here is the relevant code:

```
$(function() {
window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'My chart'
    },
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
    },
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log()` the data to ensure it is being loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading data in Highchart and Highstock works the same. Notice, that data requires the data module to be loaded additionally. Your options seem good, so it can be the issue.

[Highcharts data documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data):

> It requires the modules/data.js file to be loaded.

Check the demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/afy6m3tb/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>

<h3>Raw data</h3>
<pre id="data">Date,series A, series B, series C, series D, series E, series F
3/01/2001,100,100,100,100,100,100
4/01/2001,100.0723,100.0766,100.1225,100.1446,100.1687,100.1325
5/01/2001,100.0399,99.9775,100.0809,100.3502,100.1117,100.5127
6/01/2001,100.3103,100.3867,100.2974,100.5214,100.4256,100.6885
7/01/2001,101.3379,102.0689,100.686,100.6031,100.9522,100.7648
</pre>
```

JS:

```
window.chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  data: {
    csv: document.getElementById('data').innerHTML
  }
});
```

Comment: Haha yep that was it...I had the data module in my main index file but not in the file I was testing the chart in...silly me! Thanks!